# v-on:click not working with datatables

Tags: laravel, vue.js, datatable

I am using yajra datatables:

```
 var table = $("#dt_user_draw").DataTable({
                    destroy: true,
                    processing: true,
                    responsive: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    ordering: false,
                    "ajax": {
                        "method": "GET",
                        "url": 'url'
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "data": "user"
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "email"
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "registered_at",
                        },
                        {
                            "render": function (data, wea, row) {

                                return '<i v-on:click="showDrawUser" class="nav-icon far fa-eye fa-fw " aria-hidden="true" title="Ver Draw"></i>';
                            }
                        },                            
                    ]
                });
```

In the last row, add v-on:click but this is not working. I do not how to do to vue render after datatables load

Comment: show your js code as well

Comment: @Helpinghand he already show his code